# GL_INVALID_VALUE on glTextureStorage3D with cubemap arrays

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

I'm getting a GL_INVALID_VALUE when calling glTextureStorage3D on cubemap array textures. My code is quite abstracted but dumping the raw gl code from the texture creation to gl error boils down to this :

```
[SafeGL DUMP] glCreateTextures(glTargets[uint32_t(type)], 1, &id_) // glTargets[uint32_t(type)] = GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARRAY
[SafeGL DUMP] glTextureParameteri(id_, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR)
[SafeGL DUMP] glTextureParameteri(id_, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
[SafeGL DUMP] glTextureStorage3D(id_, mipLevels, glFormats[uint32_t(format_)], width, height, depth) // mipLevels = 1, glFormats[uint32_t(format_)] = GL_RG16F, width = 1024, height = 1024, depth = 4
/!\ GL ERROR 501: GL_INVALID_VALUE -- Breaking to debugger.
```

The GL spec specifies that *"An INVALID_VALUE error is generated if width, height, or depth is negative."* Except in my case it's not...

My only guess is that I'm either encountering an undocumented error that's vendor-specific (GL 4.4 context on nvidia 375.70 driver), or I'm doing something completely wrong but then I'm at a complete loss as to what.

Any idea ?

EDIT: Just updated driver to 378.66, to no avail.

Comment: `glTextureStorage3D` and `glCreateTextures` are OpenGL 4.5 functions, but you are creating 4.4 context.

Comment: @SurvivalMachine: likely that 4.4 is the requested format, but the driver gave 4.5, otherwise `glCreateTextures` won't even work.

Comment: @peppe Yup that was it! Found that while meticulously reading the whole spec for glTexStorage3D. Marking as resolved :)

Comment: @peppe it would be nice if any of you write the solution as the answer to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `depth` is not divisible by 6. When you use cubemap arrays, you don't deal with layers, you deal with "layerfaces".

See also [here](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Cubemap_Texture#Cubemap_array_textures).